# deploy multiple independent applications to appengine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

As per official documentation there can be only one app engine instance per project,
My question is, is it possible to deploy multiple independents django application to appengine ?
In other terms using appengine as a hosting platform for django apps .

Nowhere in the documentation or tutorials i have seen something like that done

How about using it to deploy multiple independents wordpress instances ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for is called [**App Engine Services**](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/configuration-files).

As well you have mentioned, you only can have 1 App Engine App per project, but this app can have multiple services which for your case can be translated as multiple apps.

Every single service will have its own `app.yaml`. Let's say you have the following struct:

```
Apps/
├── app1
│   ├── app.yaml
│   └── django_files
├── app2
│   ├── app2.yaml
│   └── django_files
├── app3
│   ├── app3.yaml
│   └── django_files
└── app4
    ├── app4.yaml
    └── django_files
```

Then the `app.yaml` can contain the following:

```
runtime: python38

#no adding the service: because this will be the default service or app
#more configs go here...
```

For the app2.yaml

```
runtime: python38
service: app2
#more configs go here...
```

You will notice that we added the `service` config which defines to which service this app will be deployed. If the `service` is not defined, the app will be deployed always to the default service.

The services are isolated, i.e., they do not communicate but if needed those can [interact between them](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/communicating-between-services).

And finally, you can map every service to a custom domain. For example, `mydomain.com` can route to the default app, `app2.mydomain.com` be routed to the second one an so on. You can learn how to map a custom domain [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/mapping-custom-domains) and how to route the requests to your services [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/how-requests-are-routed).

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer is the right one to achieve what you want to do. However, I'm writing this answer to say you to not do this!

- To create a project is free, you can create 1 project per app.
- With App Engine, you have 28h of F1 instance free per day and per project. Each new project allows you leveraging this free tier!
- The wordpress instance are differents, so the database are different. If you use the same project the same database is used. You can also create different database (or schema inside the same database instance) for each app, but at the end, all the wordpress instance will be able to reach the database instance of others app.
- If you have custom need, cleaning or something special to perform, doing this on only one wordpress instance deploy on only one project is easier and with less risk on the side wordpress instance.

There were my pieces of advice!

Comment: I see your point, but the number of projects per account is limited . And for the SQL i can create a cloud SQL instance per wordpress instance so there is no concern about database isolation

Comment: If you have a free account, yes, i agree you are limited in number of project

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere isnt there a limit of five projects per billing account and what if a company has to set up say more than hundreds of wordpress projects for each client ?

Comment: Yes there is a first limit. But you can extend it. Corporates contract haven't that limit. As individual you have, but if you provision your billing account of 10€ you can unlock more project (up to 25 by memory). Just to prove that you really want to use more Google Cloud. I personally did it.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere were you able to ssh into all your App Engines, if you used their standard enviornment ? As per the docs, ssh debbuging is enabled only on flexible env, which is needed for prod

Comment: No, you can't SSH in the instance of AppEngine standard.